# UIDatePicker background color changes on second viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

As title mentions, I am having issues using UIDatePicker component.
I am changing it's background color which doesn't work when opening ViewController for the first time. If I dismiss it and then return to that ViewController again, code works. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
var datePickerView:UIDatePicker!

// in viewDidLoad
datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
datePickerView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
datePickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
dateTextField.inputView = datePickerView
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `close it and then return to that ViewController again`? Close the app?

Comment: @Dravidian what I ment with that is dismiss ViewController.

Comment: ok..just add your picker code in main thread like dispatch_async(dispathch_get_mainQueue ....{}

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, tried and it doesn't help.

Comment: where you added your pickerview on View?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS it is in code above:
dateTextField.inputView = datePickerView

Comment: ohhhk...sorry I missed that line

Comment: @ZassX Do you mean that the background isn't black the first time you open it?

Comment: @SamM yes, background is default white color when it is opened first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange. Was playing with code a bit and found out that setting UIDatePickers `locale` caused UIDatePicker to not appear correctly.

```
datePickerView.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
```

Still don't know why. If you have any suggestion please feel free to comment below in the meantime I will find a workaround for this problem.

Comment: Same problem, your fix doesn't help :(

Comment: @ArtemZ.have you tried removing line where you are setting locale? This solved my issue.

Comment: I don't set locale :(

Answer (score 0):

**viewDidLoad** is that scope where you have to do any thing once.

**viewWillAppear** gets called every time the view appears.

Try placing it in `viewWillAppear` If even this doesn't sort out your issue try using *dispatch_async* to call your code asynchronously